# How to skip dependency with vcpkg?

Tags: c++, dependencies, cgal, mpfr, vcpkg

I am trying to install [`cgal`](https://www.cgal.org/index.html) with [`vcpkg`](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) and getting an error that `mpfr` dependency can't be installed, because [it's site](http://www.mpfr.org) is unavailable. Can I skip this dependency?

```
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Starting package 1/88: mpfr:x86-windows
Building package mpfr[core]:x86-windows...
-- Downloading http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-4.0.2/mpfr-4.0.2.tar.xz...
-- Downloading http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-4.0.2/mpfr-4.0.2.tar.xz... Failed. Status: 7;"Couldn't connect to server"
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_download_distfile.cmake:175 (message):

      Failed to download file.
      If you use a proxy, please set the HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY environment
      variables to "https://user:password@your-proxy-ip-address:port/".
      Otherwise, please submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues
```

Comment: I don't know if vcpkg will let you do it, but unless you know cgal well and are certain you don't need mpfr (don't use Epeck in particular), skipping the dependency seems like a bad idea. It would be better to find a way to let it know about alternate locations where you can get mpfr (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mpfr/ and its mirrors, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

One can control the dependencies with `Build-Depends` field in the `CONTROL` file.  In your case `ports\cgal\CONTROL`

For more information; https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/maintainers/control-files.md#control-files

However you you remove this dependency most probable you won't manage to build `cgal`